# SSL website not fully secure due to ajax

Tags: ajax, ssl

I installed SSL on my website, but I keep receiving a message saying: Your connection to this site is not fully secure.

I checked the site on whynopadlock.com and the result was this URL: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Now the problem is that I am not sure how to change this to https instead of http. I will be thankful if someone could assist me with this.

Here's the website: https://www.splitshopbg.com/en/

I tried to search for another thread on this issue but I couldn't really find a resolution.

Thanks in advance,
Pavel.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have added script with direct URL in website, then you need to do just simple thing,

Replace this

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

with secure URL

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: My problem is that I cannot locate this line. In which file should I look for it?

Comment: In which page this error show? means category page, homepage etc.

Comment: it appears on any page of the website

Comment: It means it added from head reference using any custom extension. Please check all extension layout files.

Comment: I checked all my extensions layout files and I didn't find such line in any of them. It's a big mystery :) Sorry, but I'm not a developer and I find it hard to resolve this issue. If you can help me out I would be grateful.

Comment: I suspect that this is due to the extension I'm using to change my background image. Let me know if I should paste here any of the files of this ext.

Comment: I just reloaded my Background image and now the padlock appears in front of my website URL. When I look at the source, the ajax link is still the same (http), but the error message does not appear any more.

Comment: That extension have any layout file in frontend folder then look into that, Or if that extension have any template file then also look into that asa well.